# Finding N keys with highest value in hash, keeping order

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

In a Ruby script,

- I have a hash that has sentences as keys and relevance scores as values.
- I want to retrieve an array containing the N most relevant sentences (highest scores).
- I want to retain the order in which these sentences are extracted.

Given:

```
hash = {
  'This is the first sentence.' => 5,
  'This is the second sentence.' => 1,
  'This is the last sentence.' => 6
}
```

Then:

```
choose_best(hash, 2)
```

Should return:

```
['This is the first sentence.', 'This is the last sentence.']
```

All the methods I can think of involve reordering the hash, thus losing the order of the sentences. What would be the best way to tackle this?

Comment: You now that hashes don't have an order, right? Do you want to make this Ruby 1.9 only?

Comment: What do you want to happen when there are sentences with ties, and you cannot select exactly the N most?

Comment: From what I understand, hashes are not "made" to be ordered, although insertion order will be kept in Ruby > 1.9. I've long committed this particular application to Ruby > 1.9, so it doesn't bother me too much to break BC. But if there is a philosophically better way to accomplish this, please enlighten me!

Comment: @louism: I tried to do so in my answer :)

Comment: @sawa, I take care of ties somewhere else in the code before extracting sentences - just assume that there won't be ties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following monster:

```
hash.map(&:reverse).each_with_index
                   .sort_by(&:first).reverse
                   .take(2)
                   .sort_by(&:last)
                   .map { |(_,s),_| s }
```

Another functional one:

```
hash.to_a.values_at(*hash.values.each_with_index
                         .sort.reverse
                         .map(&:last)
                         .sort.take(2))
         .map(&:first)
```

Note however, that as an unordered data structure, a hash table is not really suitable for this use case (although the order is remembered in Ruby 1.9). You should use an array instead (the sorting code remains the same):

```
sentences = [
  ['This is the first sentence.',  5],
  ['This is the second sentence.', 1],
  ['This is the last sentence.',   6],
]
```

Comment: Beautiful! Can you explain what `|(_,s),_| s` does or link to a page with more information? I've never seen anything like it before.

Comment: @louism: That's actually the ugly part. In the course of sorting first by descending rank, then by ascending index, I choose to represent the items as arrays of the form `[[rank, sentence], index]`. After the sorting, we want to extract just the sentence, so we use array destructuring / pattern matching to assign each item to `(_,s),_` inside the block, which will throw away the rank and the index, and assign the sentence to the variable `s`.

Comment: Thanks. Your second approach is a bit [faster](https://gist.github.com/1921100) than the first one, but it only works on hashes, so I think I'm going to settle with the first.

Comment: @louism: If you are concerned about speed, you could sure do a lot better than both my approaches. They are actually not quite efficient, but unless proven necessary, I usually don't pre-optimize and try to make the code as readable as possible instead of as fast as possible. The second piece of code also works on arrays, it only needs minimal adaptions (no `.to_a` and `.map(&:last)` instead of `.values`).

Comment: I updated the [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/1921100) and it turns out Sawa's approach is actually the fastest. I wish I could accept both great answers, but I'll keep this one as I accepted it first.

Comment: @louism: It's still far from the fastest possible. Also, that test set should be hardly realistic. I can only repeat, only worry about performance if actual profiling has turned out that this particular code is a bottleneck in your application. If this is not the case, choose readability over speed and optimize the parts of your code that actually get executed very often.

Answer (score 2):

```
def extract hash, n
  min = hash.values.sort[-n]
  a = []
  i = 0
  hash.each{|k, v| (a.push(k) and i += 1) if i < n and v >= min}
  a
end
```

Comment: Doesn't this fail when the you add `'oh, one more'=>6` to the hash ?

Comment: @steenslag That situation does not happen. See the questioner's comment on the question. But even if such situation happens, how does it fail?

Comment: @steenslag Thanks. That was my crucial mistake. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = {
  'This is the first sentence.' => 5,
  'This is the second sentence.' => 1,
  'This is the last sentence.' => 6
}

cutoff_val = hash.values.sort[-2] #cf. sawa
p hash.select{|k,v| v >= cutoff_val } 
# =>{"This is the first sentence."=>5, "This is the last sentence."=>6}
```

Comment: I see. I realized that under the condition that there is not ties, the condition to count the number of elements in my answer was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Ruby 2.2.0, [`Enumerable#max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-trunk/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) takes an optional integer argument that makes it return an array instead of just a single element.  Therefore, we can do:

```
hash = {
  'This is the first sentence.' => 6,
  'This is the second sentence.' => 1,
  'This is the last sentence.' => 5
 }

p hash.max_by(2, &:last).map(&:first).sort_by { |k| hash.keys.index k }
# => ["This is the first sentence.", "This is the last sentence."]
```

The call to `sort_by` at the end guarantees the sentences are in the right order, as you requested.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = hash.sort_by { |sentence, score| score }.reverse
```

The array a now contains pairs of values of your top scoring sentences.  You can select the first N of them.

```
hash = {"foo" => 7, "bar" => 2, "blah" => 3 }
a = hash.sort_by { |sentence, score| score }.reverse
=> [["foo", 7], ["blah", 3], ["bar", 2]]
```

Comment: One of the requirements was to retain the original order.

Comment: My bad.  I misunderstood his requirement when he spoke of reordering the hash.  I thought he was looking for something that would not disturb the order of the hash (i.e don't propose a solution that involves changing the hash order).